# FQL query returns only some data

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have a problem with the Facebook API. I'm trying to get post likes/comments/shares count.
My FQL query looks like this:

```
'SELECT like_info, comment_info, share_info from stream 
WHERE post_id="' . $fanpage['Fanpage']['fb_id'] . '_' . $post['Post']['fb_id'] . '"  
AND (is_hidden = 0 OR is_hidden = 1)';
```

Basically variables explain themselves - `$fanpage` is fanpage data, `$post` is post data. It works for every post but one, this is what api returns:

```
(int) 0 => array(
    'like_info' => array(
        'can_like' => false,
        'like_count' => '0',
        'user_likes' => false
    ),
    'comment_info' => array(
        'can_comment' => false,
        'comment_count' => '0'
    ),
    'share_info' => array(
        'can_share' => true,
        'share_count' => '85'
    )
)
```

And i have no clue why like_count is 0 when post has over 500 likes, can_like is false even tho i can like the post, user_likes false while I already liked the post. Any idea what might be causing this? My app has read_stream and user_likes permissions given.

Comment: What kind of access token are you using? And, have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/684361601632430/

Comment: @Tobi Im using user access token. Unfortunately the link you provided is about losing share data - as you can see it's the only thing im getting correctly :)